# Css box shadow lifted corner

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply the lifted shadow effect with css to a box but when I use the negative z-index the shadow goes behind the box and the effect that should stay at the bottom of the box disappears too instead of staying for the effect to take place.

Here is my code and how it should look: http://jsfiddle.net/K7tSy/4/

```
.boxz:before {
      z-index: 1; 
      position: absolute; 
      content: "";
      bottom: 8px;
      left: 28px;
      width: 90%; 
      top: 80%;
      max-width:300px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7); 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
             box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg); 
         -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg); 
           -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
              transform: rotate(2deg);
   }
```

And this is the test site http://www.codita.ro/asd/  notice if I set the z-index to negative the effect disappears instead of showing up like on the fiddle.  Can someone explain whats preventing it from displaying like on in the fiddle when I set the negative z-index?

Comment: something is preventing the shadow to remain at the bottom after i use the negative z-index to hide the unnecesary behind the box... cant figure out why...

Comment: If you remove z-index it's display shadow ?

Comment: yes it still displays if you remove z-index

Comment: this is so frustrating, ive been trying to figure it out since yesterday with no luck. the shadow wont display at the bottom no matter what i try :(

Comment: You want to display shadow outside of box ? bottom part ?

Comment: yes, like you can see it on jsfiddle example.. but when i put it on the site it disappears all togheter after i set the z-index negative

Comment: let me know if you need the whole website code on jsfiddle to take a better look etc.. will upload anything you need right away. thanks

Comment: just discovered that if i cancel 2 divs the shadow will work, you can see it up on codita.ro/asd   the 2 divs are:        <code>           #wrapmain {
  background: url(images/bg_repeat.jpg);
}

.wrapall {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 32px #a5abae;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 32px #a5abae;
  box-shadow: 0px -5px 32px #a5abae;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
} <code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `content : ""` from  class `.boxz:before`.

Hope this will give you result as you want.

I have tested in your http://www.codita.ro/asd/

**OP**

Add `background-color:#FFFFFF` in your `wrapall` class.

Comment: not working... as i said the 2 divs that i have posted in my previous comment are blocking the shadow to display when set to negative z-index, you can see on codita i have removed the 2 divs and it shows now but the 2 divs are wrapping the site so they are a must...

Comment: i have found the problem. the boxes are inside a div called .wrapall .  if i remove its background color (background-color: #fff;) the shadow will show up as it should. problem is i need that background color to be white, how to get around this? thanks

Comment: ok now shadow display back side of box so exaclty what you want now ?

Comment: it only shows if i remove the background from the containing element, now i need it to show without removing that background because i need it white..

Comment: Add backgeound-color:#FFFFFF to your wrapall class and then try.

Comment: not working, if i add any background color to the wrapall, it hides the shadow effect from the bottom of the boxes. if i remove the bg color, the shadow shows but not on the white bg as i need :) this is tricky

Comment: well i have used the rgba with opacity so i have a lil different white bg with grayish shadow instead of black.. thanks alot Devang for your time and inputs!

Answer (score 2):

Your element is a child of a container that doesn't have a z-index stacking context. If you are putting it within a div for a background color, style the div with a "position: relative" and z-index = 1 to set a stacking context within the container.

Ref:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUnderstanding_z-index%2FThe_stacking_context